# Returning row where all related WHEREs match

Tags: mysql, select, join, many-to-many, where-clause

I need to return a result that matches ALL of the WHERE statements on a many-to-many relation. To explain:

I have a table structure like this.

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`));

CREATE TABLE `product_has_tag` (
  `product_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `tag` (
  `tag_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `value` VARCHAR(30) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tag_id`));
```

Now I have a situation like this:

```
Product: {
  [product_id:1], 
  [product_id:2], 
  [product_id:3]};
Tags: {
  [tag_id:1, value:'XX'],
  [tag_id:2, value:'YY']}
ProductHasTag: {
  [product_id:1, tag_id:1],
  [product_id:1, tag_id:2],
  [product_id:2, tag_id:1],
  [product_id:3, tag_id:2]}
```

Basically, there is one product that has both tags and rest have jsut one. Now I need a SQL search criteria that will return ONLY the product that has both tags associated with it. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN product_has_tag USING(product_id) 
LEFT JOIN tag USING(tag_id) 
WHERE value LIKE '%X%' AND value LIKE '%Y%'
```

which obviously does not work as searched values are not in ONE tag but in TWO. 
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but could you not use `OR` in your `WHERE`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for looking at my question! Unfortunately using OR will return ALL products and I need only Product with id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change `WHERE` to `HAVING` and use `SUM CASE WHEN`

```
SELECT `product`.`product_id`    -- *
FROM `product` 
LEFT JOIN product_has_tag 
  USING(product_id) 
LEFT JOIN tag 
   USING(tag_id) 
GROUP BY `product`.`product_id`
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN `value` LIKE '%X%' THEN 1 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN `value` LIKE '%Y%' THEN 1 END) > 0
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a1c1/9/0)**</kbd>

Comment: Looks brilliant and simple and it works as expected... any chance you could elaborate on performance of the above? Is something like this very costly?

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash Performance mainly depends on your table structures and indexes you have. One note is that in any solution you will use `value LIKE '%X%'` is not SARGable and query optimizer won't use indexes on `value` column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle the two different tags as if they were two different columns. That requires some fancy join work.

This query gives your products matching your first criterion.

```
SELECT p.*, t1.value tag1
  FROM product p
  JOIN product_has_tag pt1 ON p.product_id =  pt1.product_id
  JOIN tag t1 ON pt1.tag_id = t1.tag_id AND t1.value LIKE '%X%'
```

You can add a few things to this query to get both tags you want.

```
SELECT p.*, t1.value tag1, t2.value tag2
  FROM product p
  JOIN product_has_tag pt1 ON p.product_id =  pt1.product_id
  JOIN tag t1 ON pt1.tag_id = t1.tag_id AND t1.value LIKE '%X%'
  JOIN product_has_tag pt2 ON p.product_id =  pt2.product_id
  JOIN tag t2 ON pt2.tag_id = t2.tag_id AND t2.value LIKE '%Y%'
```

The JOIN items will cause this query to isolate your product rows with both matching tags.

Your `value LIKE '%match%'` pattern in this query will cause poor performance. If you can use either `value LIKE 'match%'` or `value = 'match'` performance will be able to exploit an index on the `value` column.

Comment: Thank for the answer Ollie! I may have potentially 10 tags and 10 search terma so multiple joins don't look to inviting. +1 for turning my attention to '%match%' inefficiency!

Comment: Don't worry about the multiple join cascades. If you can beat the `LIKE` inefficiency this will all still perform reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

You can sum up the matched tags and only return the results with 2 matches.

```
SELECT * FROM product
LEFT JOIN product_has_tag USING(product_id) 
LEFT JOIN tag USING(tag_id) 
WHERE value LIKE '%X%' OR value LIKE '%Y%' 
GROUP BY product_id  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id) = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Looks simple and tempting but my structure/query is potentially more complicated with other joins (like translations) that may return more than one hit per row. So unless I misunderstand the above, I could get accidental SUM(*)=2 even if only one of the ORs hits... Am I correct?

Comment: @RandomWhiteTrash Yes you are correct see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5fa22/2/0 by the way it needs to be `SUM(1) or COUNT(*)`

Comment: @lad2025 addet DISTINCT to only count tags once per product